# Detached entity still in persistence context

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Given the following code

```
@Transactional
@GetMapping("/load")
public String load() throws InterruptedException {
    final Order order87 = ... load via dao which uses the entityManager
    log.info("1 load order87 is in persistence context: {}", entityManager.contains(order87));
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    entityManager.detach(order87);
    log.info("2 load order87 is in persistence context: {}", entityManager.contains(order87));
    return "loading done";
}

@Transactional
@GetMapping("/save")
public String save() throws InterruptedException {
    final Order order87 = ... load via dao which uses the entityManager
    log.info("1 save order87 is in persistence context: {}", entityManager.contains(order87));
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    log.info("2 save order87 is in persistence context: {}", entityManager.contains(order87));
    order87.setName("Cup");
    orderDao.save(order87);
    return "saving done";
}
```

When both methods are executed right one after the other - since there is only one persistence context per entityManager - I would have expected the following:

```
1 load order87 is in persistence context: true
1 save order87 is in persistence context: true
2 load order87 is in persistence context: false
2 save order87 is in persistence context: false
```

but it was

```
1 load order87 is in persistence context: true
1 save order87 is in persistence context: true
2 load order87 is in persistence context: false
2 save order87 is in persistence context: true
```

Both methods run in separate transactions but they share the entityManager and as well its persistence context. Both the entityManager and order87 have corresponding hashcodes in both methods, i.e. it is the same object and the same entitymanager. The order has as well the same persistent (database) id.

And since: "Only one Java instance with the same persistent identity may exist in a persistence context at any time. For example, if an Employee with a persistent identity (or id) of 158 exists in the persistence context, then no other Employee object with its id set to 158 may exist within that same persistence context." ("Pro JPA 2", 2nd edition, 2013) I would expect the order to be detached as well in the save method after the load method has detached it.

How does that work?

**Update**
I used `System.identityHashCode` to verify the objects identity and as a result the entitymanager is the same but the order is a different instance in the two methods. But they still have the same database identity and there should be only one instance, right?

Comment: Why do you think two transactions would share the persistence context? What would be the point of using transactions if one of them could see the changes made by the other?

Comment: If you want a persistence context shared between transactions, inject the `EntityManager` using `@PersistenceContext(type = EXTENDED)` instead

Comment: ok, thanks. Got it.